# prefixing in stylus mixin

Tags: css, stylus

I have this stylus mixin:

```
display()
  display: (-ms-)arguments
  display: (-webkit-)arguments
  display: arguments
```

Which is generating this in CSS:

```
.nav ul li a {
  display: -ms- flex;
  display: -webkit- flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

However what I want to achieve:

```
.nav ul li a {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

How I can achieve this with Stylus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use it like this since this is a special occasion for displaying as flex?

```
display()
  display: -ms-flex
  display: -webkit-flex
  display: flex

.nav ul li a
  display()
```

Or even rename it to `displayFlex()` so you always know what it is about.